# Parsing and getting nested json objects using gson java

Tags: java, gson

I have this json file:

```
{
  "Update tree": {
    "average time": 0.01610115085649609,
    "best time": 0.003310859220941582,
    "count": 651,
    "success rate": 100,
    "worst time": 0.621779361692829
  },
  "Update renderables": {
    "average time": 0.1988377572034353,
    "best time": 0.0003510859220941582,
    "count": 649,
    "success rate": 100,
    "worst time": 12.8709652214104
  },
  "Before render": {
    "average time": 0.5206290903024032,
    "best time": 0.01522995241633128,
    "count": 188,
    "success rate": 100,
    "worst time": 81.06473259514415
  },
  "Rendering": {
    "average time": 4.425231035278629,
    "best time": 0.4979532268296139,
    "count": 214,
    "success rate": 100,
    "worst time": 71.34537426614806
  },
  "After render": {
    "average time": 0.06479598048728916,
    "best time": 0.0301288189105684,
    "count": 563,
    "success rate": 100,
    "worst time": 0.6413134310963844
  }
}
```

where I want to calculate the average of all avergaes in each json object how do I iterate through the json objects?

I am trying to get all avergaes values sum them up and calculate their average

EDIT:

I have this for loop which I want to iterate through each object (and not getting its member name but to actually iterate through the objects and get the values and then sum them up):

```
for(int i=0; i<json.size(); i++){
            sumAllAverages(json.getAsJsonObject());
        }

private static void sumAllAverages(JsonObject asJsonObject) {
        sum += Float.parseFloat(asJsonObject.get("average time").toString());
    }
```

Comment: I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GSON you can just deserialize this to a map like:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map =
        new Gson().fromJson(getResourceStreamReader("file.json"), type);
```

*getResourceStreamReader("file.json")* is just a helper method to get your JSON from a resource file. It can be String or any reader.

To have all the average times (for example):

```
Set<Double> averageTimes = map.values().stream()
    .map(v -> v.get("average time")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

To inspect the averages from this map you can for example do this:

```
averageTimes.forEach(averageTime -> System.out.println(averageTime));
```

This produces:

> 0.01610115085649609
> 0.1988377572034353
> 0.5206290903024032
> 4.425231035278629
> 0.06479598048728916

Further you can use reduce to sum all the values and get the total average time;

```
Double totalAverageTime = averageTimes.stream()
            .reduce((a, b) -> a + b).orElse(0D) / averageTimes.size();
```

Inspect it:

```
System.out.println(totalAverageTime);
```

and you will see:

> 1.0451190028256505

**Note**: all this calculation may be done with yet fewer lines even in one lambda but for clarity and making it easier to follow I have splitted the phases.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it in Jackson, gson should be fairly similar.

```
JsonNode time_Data;
    try {
      time_Data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonTimes); // **this is your file as a string
      double sum = 0.0;
      if(time_Data!= null) {
        for (final JsonNode valuesPacket : time_Data) {
          sum += Double.parseDouble(valuesPacket.get("average time").asText());
        }
      }
      System.out.println("sum is :"+sum);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: what maven dependancy are you using for the second line (e.g. readTree)

Comment: ```<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
      </dependency>```